# Using a skillset when adding documents to Azure Search Index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I was able to successfully use a skillset (keyword extraction) for a column using an Indexer importing data from a Cosmos DB collection. However I want to eventually use the .NET SDK's DocumentsOperationsExtensions's IndexAsync() method to add documents to the index ( as I already have a change feed listener on the Cosmos DB collection and want to leverage that instead of running a periodic indexer querying Cosmos DB).

But I don't see how I can specify the skillset to be used when adding the document to the index using the SDK approach (or even the REST API one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents). Is this a supported scenario? Or are we obligated to use an Indexer if we have to leverage skillsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or are we obligated to use an Indexer if we have to leverage skillsets?

Correct. Skillsets and cognitive search functionality are only available via the Indexer mechanism (as stated in the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-defining-skillset)).

They are not available via the `Index` API (SDK or REST).
FYI - you can still perform Indexer and Skillset management (if you do choose to go that route) via the [preview SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search/7.0.0-preview)

Comment: Is there a plan to add a way specify a skillset when adding documents using Document Operations SDK/ REST API?

Comment: Not currently in our plans yet unfortunately. Please do add it to the user voice page for Azure search to indicate your request: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search